# Export the real roots of an equation

Tags: equation-solving, export, version-11

I wish to find the roots of y (with only its real part) for different values of r in range 1(0.01)30. I have tried the following:

```
b = 2.6666;
Pr = 10;
y = Roots[x^3 + x^2 (1 + b + Pr) + x (b + b (r - 1) + Pr*b) + 2*Pr*b (r - 1) == 0, x];
q1 = y /. {r -> {0}}
q2 = y /. {r -> {0.01}}
q3 = y /. {r -> {0.02}}
q4 = y /. {r -> {0.03}}
```

Is there a neater way to do this? Also, I want to export these roots to an excel sheet as shown here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

"13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

b = 2.6666;
Pr = 10;
```

**EDIT 2:** Modified to return real part of roots rather than real roots.

```
(table = Prepend[
    Table[{r, Sequence @@
       Re[SolveValues[
        x^3 + x^2 (1 + b + Pr) + x (b + b (r - 1) + Pr*b) + 
          2*Pr*b (r - 1) == 0, x]]},
     {r, 0, 0.03, 0.01}],
    {"r", "x1", "x2", "x3"}]) // Grid
```

**EDIT:** Or, for earlier versions without [`SolveValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveValues.html), use

```
(table = 
   Prepend[Table[{r, 
      Sequence @@ Re[(x /. 
         Solve[x^3 + x^2 (1 + b + Pr) + x (b + b (r - 1) + Pr*b) + 
            2*Pr*b (r - 1) == 0, x])]}, {r, 0, 0.03, 
      0.01}], {"r", "x1", "x2", "x3"}]) // Grid
```

[image]

```
Export["test.csv", table];

Import["test.csv"] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: The posted code isn't getting solved for x. I am using Mathematica version 11. @Bob Hanlon

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I use it on version 11? @BobHanlon

Comment: Something is not right. For example, in range r=20(0.01)30, only a single root is displayed. I want to get all the three roots but with their real parts. @BobHanlon

Comment: Edited. Your range specification makes no sense in Mathematica. Presumably, you mean for the iterator to be `{r, 20, 30, 0.01}`

Comment: Oh Yes I want the iterator to be {r, 20, 30, 0.01}. However, after using the edited code, there is still no difference in the output . @BobHanlon

Comment: I forgot to take out the domain specification (`Reals`) in the second block of code. Try it now.

Comment: It's just perfect now! Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate your effort. @BobHanlon